# Calling a URL within a variable to receive image

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, nsdata, nsurl

I'm trying to grab an image from an URL. Now I know you can do this by using `let url = NSURL(string: "http://")`. But what if you have a variable that has a url in it.

Example: `self.testAd.getImgPath()` has `http://www.Woods.com/images/imgs/MAU_SouthTrees_mobi.jpg
/as/img.cfm?gphc=14490`.

How do we call `testAd.getImgPath()` to recognize the url and grab the image? I'm using this code below to grab the content and insert it into an image.

```
let url = NSURL(string:)    
var err: NSError?
var imageData :NSData = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!,options: NSDataReadingOptions.DataReadingMappedIfSafe, error: &err)!
var bgImage = UIImage(data:imageData)
imageView.image = bgImage
imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
```

Comment: My answer presumes that `getImgPath()`'s return type is `String`.  Is this the case?  Or does it return something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NSURL`'s initializer, `NSURL(string:)` takes a `string` parameter, and it doesn't have to be a literal string.  We can pass a string variable in here.

```
if let url = NSURL(string:testAd.getImgPath()) {
    var err: NSError?
    if let imageData = NSData(contentsOfURL:url, options:.DataReadingMappedIfSafe, error:&err) {
        let bgImage = UIImage(data:imageData)
        imageView.image = bgImage
        imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
    }
}
```

Comment: Yea that was it! Thanks! It looks like just a syntax error go figure. But yea this def works. What is the difference between .DataReadingMappedIfSafe compared to NSDataReadingOptions?

Comment: Nothing.  With Swift `enums`, including the part before the dot is optional.  I just omitted that part.

Comment: Just wondering would there be a reason for this to be throwing BAD Instruction errors? It seems like sometimes this works and sometimes it doesn't. In my log it says fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.

Comment: Did you exactly copy mine? Or is it part mine, part yours? The code in question definitely has lots of cases that could throw that exception.

Comment: its part mine and part yours here what i did  let url = NSURL(string:testAd.getImgPath())
        var err: NSError?
        let imageData = NSData(contentsOfURL:url!, options:.DataReadingMappedIfSafe, error:&err)
        
        let imageE = UIImage(data:imageData!) ***where imageE is inserted into a button background

Comment: Switch it to be exactly like mine or post a new question.

Comment: It throws the exception on the imageE = UIImage(data:imageData!)

Comment: Okay so yea it does work I must of added in things that shouldnt have been added. Thanks again and sorry for wasting your time on this mistake!